# How if(some pointer) in C works?

Tags: c, pointers

I'm a beginner in C and I'm trying to understand the concept of pointer arithmetic:

I have a code like this :

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main(){
    int a[10];
    if(a)
        printf("%d\n",*a);
}
```

Which prints the address of first element in array `a`. That's fine. But in my `printf` statement I'm using the `*` operator to print the value.

But when I look at my `if` statement, I wonder how without `*` operator, `if` is working on `a`? 
I mean without `*` operator, how the `if` statement accesses the object the pointer points to?

I guess i'm clear enough about my doubt, thanks in advance.

Comment: It actually should print the *contents* of the first element.

Comment: `a` is unitiialised, so the value of the first element in `a` will be completely random.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Which prints the address of first element in array a

In your code `*a` is equivalent with `a[0]`. **You're not printing any address**, just some uninitialized value.

#### EDIT as per comment:

> no my question is without * operator, how the if statement accesses
>   the object the pointer points to

In your code `if (a)` doesn't access the contents, it only tests **the address of a** - which will never evaluate to 0.

Comment: no my question is without `*` operator, how the `if` statement accesses the object the pointer points to?

Answer (score 0):

In C there is no type for a boolean so the body of an if-statement is executed when the condition doesn't equal 0 (zero). And it's quite sure that `a` doesn't point to the address `0`, so the condition evaluates to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

```
      if (a)
```

basically checks if a is a null pointer.

When you declare 
                int a[10]
you allocate a space of memory of 10 integers, starting at the address 'a'.

When you printf *a the compiler prints the first element becuase you're telling it to print the element at the address *(a + offset) which in your case offset = 0;

To convince yourself you can try doing

```
     int *a=null;
      if (a) 
       {
          //code here won't be executed because a points to a null reference
       }
```